# How to refine a leaf's range in YANG model?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I have a grouping like -

```
  grouping threshold-value-grouping {
    container threshold-value {
      description "Threshold value";
      leaf upper-limit-val {
        description
          "Upper limit";
        type uint32 {
          range "1..60000";
        }
      }
      leaf lower-limit-val {
        description
          "Lower limit";
        type uint32 {
          range "1..60000";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And i want to reuse this grouping at multiple places.
But when used at different places, the range of the leaves vary.

So i am wondering how can I use the *refine* statement to achieve?
Or is there any better way to address this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Section 7.13.2 of [RFC 7950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950) explicitly specifies all possible refinements and `range` is not one of them. Neither is `type` which can also be seen in the ABNF grammar (section 14):

```
refine-stmt         = refine-keyword sep refine-arg-str optsep
                       "{" stmtsep
                           ;; these stmts can appear in any order
                           *if-feature-stmt
                           *must-stmt
                           [presence-stmt]
                           *default-stmt
                           [config-stmt]
                           [mandatory-stmt]
                           [min-elements-stmt]
                           [max-elements-stmt]
                           [description-stmt]
                           [reference-stmt]
                         "}" stmtsep
```

But what you can do is to add a `must` constraint here, something like

```
uses threshold-value-grouping {
    refine threshold-value/upper-limit-val {
        must '(. >= 10 and . <= 100)' {
            error-message "Here you can only use values between 10 and 100";
        }
    }
}
```